# Proxy server question, Is Serverfault the correct place to ask?

Tags: discussion, sffaq

Would it be acceptable to ask about Squid Proxy configuration? specifically related to Delay buckets and bandwidth caps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As that is a system administration topic I can see no reason why it shouldn't be asked on SF. There have certainly been other Squid questions posted previously: [squid](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/squid)

Comment: Looking through the questions now

Comment: +1 Sounds like it would fit squarely on SF; even if it belongs somewhere else, we'll move the question as appropriate.